# RetryListenerSupport handlers executed on all @Retryables

Tags: spring, listener, spring-retry

I checked out docs and it seems (and is intuitive) that you have to register a RetryListenerSupport within the @Retryable annotation listener's arg.

But for some reason, the RetryListenerSupport gets executed on all @Retryables within the project, without adding it to any listeners args - is this the expected behaviour?

If yes, what's the listeners argument for at all?

Comment: I don't see any listener argument to `@Retryable` annotation https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/annotation/Retryable.html. What version of spring-retry are you using and do you have any example code ?

Comment: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.retry/spring-retry/1.2.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/retry/annotation/Retryable.html

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late answer but I just ran into the exact same issue.

I think the annotation was updated and the listener field was removed as it does not appear in the current documentation.

I implemented a new interceptor for my project and in order to log the retries, I implemented a RetryListener that was registered in a new RetryTemplate used inside the interceptor.

As an example is better than a long explanation, it looked like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyRetryInterceptor{
    @Bean
    public RetryOperationsInterceptor retryInterceptorCustom() {
        UniformRandomBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new BackOffPolicy(); //Configure it
        RetryPolicy retryPolicyCustom = new RetryPolicy(); //Configure it

        RetryTemplate template = RetryTemplate.builder()
                                    .customBackoff(backOffPolicy)
                                    .customPolicy(retryPolicyCustom )
                                    .withListener(new MyRetryListener())
                                    .build();
        RetryOperationsInterceptor interceptor = new RetryOperationsInterceptor();
        interceptor.setRetryOperations(template);
        return interceptor;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it inside a `@Retryable` annotation like this:

```java
@Retryable(interceptor = "retryInterceptorCustom")
```

I know this is not perfect at all so use it at your own risk.